# How to update CSS class and rel attributes for anchor link in TinyMCE 5 file_picker_callback / callback() function

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

so I'm using TinyMCE 5 and can't find how to update CSS class="" and rel="" attributes for:

```
<a class="..." rel="...." href="data.url">data.text</a>
```

anchor link with callback() function?

Couldn't find solution through documentation:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/link/

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#file_picker_callback

and Google.

My TinyMCE 5 init() JavaScript example code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        //...
        file_picker_types: 'file image',
        file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
            if (meta.filetype == 'file') {
                tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.openUrl({
                    title: 'File browser',
                    url: TINYMCE_FILE_BROWSER_URL,
                    onMessage: function (api, data) {
                        if (data.mceAction === 'fileAction') { 
                            callback(data.url, { text: data.text, 'css_classes_attribute': 'int_mark_link' });
                            api.close();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        //predefined CSS classes:
        link_class_list: [
            {title: 'None', value: ''},
            {title: 'External Link', value: 'ext_link'},
            {title: 'Internal Support Link', value: 'int_sup_link'},
            {title: 'Internal Marketing Link', value: 'int_mark_link'},
            {title: 'Other Internal Link', value: 'int_other_link'}
        ],
        //...
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A rel can be set with the rel_list

```
rel_list: [
   {title: 'None', value: ''},
   {title: 'Rel nofollow', value: 'nofollow'},
   {title: 'Rel sponsored', value: 'sponsored'}
],
```

Classes like this

```
  link_class_list: [
    {title: 'None', value: ''},
    {title: 'Bold', value: 'classbold'},
    {title: 'Extrabold', value: 'classextrabold'}
  ],
```

Comment: I know about "link_class_list" default CSS classes and the posibility to change it in Insert Dialog dropdown. But what I want is, if I have <a class="old-css-class">..</a> to update it to new CSS class: <a class="new-css-class">..</a> with Javascript: callback(data.url, { text: data.text, 'css_class': 'new-css-class' }); , and I don't know what is correct attribute that I should provide in callback: 'css_class'?